# \cs_new:nn or \@namelet

Tags: macros, expl3, csname

Before I expend the effort, has anybody defined either `\cs_new:nn` or `\@namelet`, the basic idea being that I want to write

```
\@namelet{foo}{bar}
```

or

```
\cs_new:nn {foo} {bar}
```

and have that be equivalent to

```
\let\foo = \bar
```

I have an idea of how to do this, but I'd rather not type it if I can avoid it.

Comment: `\cs_new_eq:cc`

Comment: or in old money: `\def\@namelet#1#2{\expandafter\let\csname#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname#2\endcsname}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your old money version doesn't work:  `\@namelet{foo}{bar}` would set `\foo` to `\csname` and then dump out `bar\endcsname` giving an error.

Comment: @DonHosek  it works for me. I assume that you tried it without the 2nd `\expandafter` which would then do as you describe

Comment: D'oh, I didn't see that second expandafter. I'm having a brain-freeze morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `expl3`, the equivalent to `\let` is `\cs_set_eq:NN` (or `\cs_new_eq:NN` when defining something new). Additionally applying `\csname ...\endcsname` to a argument before using it as a `N` type argument is specified with `c`, so when doing this for both arguments you end up with `\cs_set_eq:cc {foo} {bar}` (or `\cs_new_eq:cc {foo} {bar}`)

Comment: Thanks, it's always a pain to keep track of the meanings of the various argument types with expl3.

Comment: @DonHosek The idea is that there's a clear relationship ... I guess it doesn't come across to the non-initiated.

Comment: True, it's just a bit of a challenge remembering the bits as I'm initiating myself.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late to the party. :-)

I can offer a `#{`-syntax-based macro `\CsNameToCsToken` to create, e.g.,  the control-word-token `\Foo` from the character-token-sequence `Foo` or the control-word-token `\Bar` from the character-token-sequence `Bar`.

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{Foo}` → `\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{Foo}` → `\newcommand\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{Foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{Foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{Foo}\Bar` → `\expandafter\Foo\Bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{Foo}=\Bar` → `\let\Foo=\Bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{Foo}={Bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\let\Foo={Bar}` → `\let\Foo=\Bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{Foo}` → `\string\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{Foo}` → `\meaning\Foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{Foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\Foo...`  .

You can define `\@namelet`, where you can use `=` between arguments if you wish to, in terms of `\CsNameToCsToken`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%===============================================================================
%% \@namelet
%%===============================================================================
\newcommand\@namelet{\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand\Bar{This is Bar.}

\@namelet{Foo}{Bar}%
\message{^^J\string\Foo\space yields: \Foo^^J}

\@namelet{Foob}={Bar}%
\message{^^J\string\Foob\space yields: \Foob^^J}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\Bar{This is redefined Bar.}

\global\@namelet{Fooc}{Bar}%

\global\@namelet{Food}={Bar}%
\endgroup

\message{^^J\string\Fooc\space yields: \Fooc^^J}

\message{^^J\string\Food\space yields: \Food^^J}

\end{document}
```

Messages on the terminal:

```
\Foo yields: This is Bar.

\Foob yields: This is Bar.

\Fooc yields: This is redefined Bar.

\Food yields: This is redefined Bar.
```

Pitfall/caveat:

Things being surrounded by curly braces is mandatory, however, even if the name of the control-sequence in question is formed by a single token only.

E.g.,

`\@namelet ab` and `\@namelet a=b` do not work out while
`\@namelet {a}{b}` and `\@namelet {a}={b}` do work out.